# Is it possible to wrap chai.js expect functions to catch exceptions?

Tags: javascript, function, chai

I want to use the chai.js expect assertions to perform multiple tests in my code.
If a assertion is failing I want to log it and then proceed with the next one.

e.g.>

```
 expect(recvRequest.request.response.statusCode).to.equal(expResponse.statusCode);
```

`expect(recvRequest.request.response).to.have.property(headers);`

etc.
I want to be able to write multiple expects without encapsulating each one in a try catch. So I thought I write a simple wrapper for it but it failed.
I get an error at func.call

```
function exWrapper(func, arg) {
    try {
         func.call(null, arg);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
 exWrapper(expect(recvRequest.request.response.statusCode).to.equal, 120);
```

But during execution I get a: TypeError: this.assert is not a function
    at assertEqual

I checked with a typeof and expect().to.equal   is a function so what am I doing wrong? 
I hope somebody can help me.

Regards
Ruvi

Comment: You really should put them in multiple test cases if you want to record their failures individually

Comment: No, it is not a testcase I just want to check some values and report them and go on with my life.
If one of these tests fail it is not a fatal error and I want to continue.